# The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST. laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

im using CRUD laravel in my project , when im about to delete a table, get this error : The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

this is my index :

```
<a href="" class="badge bg-info"><span class="bi bi-pencil-square"></span></a>
            <form action="/datasekolah/datasiswa" method="post" class="d-inline">
              @csrf
              @method('DELETE')
              <button class="badge bg-danger border-0" onclick="return confirm('Are u sure?')"><span class="bi bi-trash"></span></button>
            </form>
```

my Controller :

```
public function destroy(Datasekolah $datasekolah)
{
    Datasekolah::destroy($datasekolah->id);
    return redirect('/datasekolah/datasiswa')->with('success', 'Data deleted!');
}
```

web :

```
Route::resource('/datasekolah/datasiswa', DatasekolahController::class)->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` and check the delete url, it has an id.

Comment: use `route()` instead of URL in the form's action attribute & always use the route function so in the future if you change the URL then you don't have to worry about changing the URL everywhere

Comment: The form action should also include the identifier of the resource to be deleted